# Unable to update a variable via the eval() function

Tags: javascript, oop

I'll try and be as clear as possible. I have a DVD object in Javascript. It has a small subset of properties that are assigned to it. I want to be able to change the value of these by passing the name of the property instead of having a function for each different one, but I can't seem to get it done and I'm pretty sure it's because I'm not familiar enough with the eval() function.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function DVDItem()
{
    var Properties = { 
              DVDShortName: "",  
              HasActivationKey: true, 
              NetInstFolderName: "", 
              AddTitlesCheck: true, 
              LocalTestCheck: true, } 

    this.updateProperty = function(propertyName, propertyValue)
    {
        var specificProperty = eval("Properties." + propertyName);
        specificProperty = propertyValue;
    }
}
```

This Way I would be able to declare an object and change it's property:

```
var DVD1 = new DVDItem();
DVD1.updateProperty("HasActivationkey", false);
```

But I'm not doing something correctly as this doesn't work. 
Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `I'm not familiar enough with the eval() function` simple forget about it, it does not exists

Comment: use `Properties[propertyName]`

Comment: The eval() is depricated, or just shouldn't be used?

Comment: because it is dangerous

Comment: Things may be happened, that you are not expected; really)

Comment: No, only the `.eval()` function on the object prototype is deprecated, not the top-level function being used here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically assign properties to a JS object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115884/dynamically-assign-properties-to-a-js-object)

Comment: Oki thanks for the info, will not use dangerous eval() anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function DVDItem() {
    var Properties = { 
        DVDShortName: "",  
        HasActivationKey: true, 
        NetInstFolderName: "", 
        AddTitlesCheck: true, 
        LocalTestCheck: true, 
    } 

    this.updateProperty = function(propertyName, propertyValue) {
        Properties[propertyName] = propertyValue;
    }
}
```

Common convention is to make the getter and setter functions the same, like this:

```
function DVDItem() {
    var attrs = {
        DVDShortName: "",
        HasActivationKey: true,
        NetInstFolderName: "",
        AddTitlesCheck: true,
        LocalTestCheck: true
    }

    this.attr = function(key, value) {
        if(value !== undefined){
            return this.attrs[key] = value;
        }else{
            return this.attrs[key];
        }
    }
}
```

As for `eval()`, here's this from the MDN documentation:

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the
>   scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways of which the similar Function is not susceptible.
>
> eval() is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to
>   invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized
>   by modern JS engines.
>
> There are safe (and fast!) alternatives to eval() for common
>   use-cases.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info on the eval() function!

Comment: “Overwhelmingly [eval is] trivailized, misused, and outright condemned by most JavaScript programmers but by looking at the work of some of the best coders you can see that , when used appropriately [it] allows for the creation of some fantastic pieces of code that wouldn’t be possible otherwise” - John Resig in Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja

Comment: it's condemned because it can lead to unexpected behavior, runs through the interpreter, and complicates the debugging process.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `eval` in this case
You can simple get what you want:

```
Properties[propertyName]
```

Read this about eval: [Why I Should not using it?](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval/)